# Changing value of member on struct in C

Tags: c, pointers

Given the following function that takes a pointer to a LinkedList:

```
int pop_front(struct LinkedList *linkedList){
    struct LinkedListNode *head = linkedList->head;
    linkedList->head = linkedList->head->next;
    return head->data;
}
```

I'd like to update my LinkedList without explicitly returning it. The above code doesn't seem to quite work when called with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct LinkedListNode {
    int data;
    struct LinkedListNode *next;
};

struct LinkedList {
    int size;
    struct LinkedListNode *head;
    struct LinkedListNode *tail;
};

struct LinkedList create_linked_list(){
    struct LinkedList linkedList;

    linkedList.size = 0;
    linkedList.head = NULL;
    linkedList.tail = NULL;

    return linkedList;
}

struct LinkedListNode *malloc_linkedlistnode(){
    struct LinkedListNode *linkedListNode;
    linkedListNode = (struct LinkedListNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct LinkedListNode));
    return linkedListNode;
}

struct LinkedList append(struct LinkedList *linkedList, int data){
    struct LinkedListNode *linkedListNode = malloc_linkedlistnode();
    linkedListNode->data = data;
    linkedList->tail->next = linkedListNode;
    linkedListNode->next = NULL;

    linkedList->tail = linkedListNode;

    if(linkedList->head == NULL){
        linkedList->head = linkedListNode;
    }

    linkedList->size++;
    return *linkedList;
}

struct LinkedList prepend(struct LinkedList *linkedList, int data){
    struct LinkedListNode *linkedListNode = malloc_linkedlistnode();
    linkedListNode->data = data;
    linkedListNode->next = linkedList->head;

    linkedList->head = linkedListNode;

    if(linkedList->tail == NULL){
        linkedList->tail = linkedListNode;
    }

    linkedList->size++;
    return *linkedList;
}

bool empty(struct LinkedList *linkedList){
    return linkedList->size != 0;
}

int value_at(struct LinkedList *linkedList, int index){
    struct LinkedListNode head = *linkedList->head;
    struct LinkedListNode next;

    for(int i = 0; i <= linkedList->size; i++){
        if(i != 0){
            head = *head.next;
        }

        if(i == index){
            return head.data;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

int pop_front(struct LinkedList *linkedList){
    struct LinkedListNode *head = linkedList->head;

    linkedList->head = linkedList->head->next;

    return head->data;
}

struct LinkedList insert_at(struct LinkedList *linkedList, int index, int data){
    struct LinkedListNode *head = linkedList->head;

    for(int i = 0; i <= linkedList->size; i++){
        if(i+1 == index){
            struct LinkedListNode *linkedListNode = malloc_linkedlistnode();
            linkedListNode->data = data;
            linkedListNode->next = head->next;
            head->next = linkedListNode;
            linkedList->size++;

            return *linkedList;
        }

        head = head->next;
    }

    return *linkedList;
}

int front(struct LinkedList *linkedList){
    return linkedList->head->data;
}

int back(struct LinkedList *linkedList){
    return linkedList->tail->data;
}

int main(){
    struct LinkedList linkedList;
    linkedList = create_linked_list();

    printf("List is %s\n", (linkedList.size ? "not empty" : "empty"));

    for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
        linkedList = prepend(&linkedList, i * 2);
    }

    linkedList = append(&linkedList, 100);

    struct LinkedListNode head = *linkedList.head;
    struct LinkedListNode tail = *linkedList.tail;

    printf("List is %s\n", (linkedList.size ? "not empty" : "empty"));

    linkedList = insert_at(&linkedList, 3, 1000);

    printf("Value at 1: %d\n", value_at(&linkedList, 1));
    printf("Value at 5: %d\n", value_at(&linkedList, 5));
    printf("Value at 3: %d\n", value_at(&linkedList, 3));
    printf("Front: %d\n", front(&linkedList));
    printf("Back: %d\n", back(&linkedList));

    printf("Pop front %d\n", pop_front(&linkedList));

    for(int i = 0; i <= linkedList.size; i++){
        if(head.next == NULL){
            printf("Size of list: %d\n", linkedList.size);
            exit(0);
        }

        if(i != 0){
            head = *head.next;
        }

        printf("Index %d: %d\n", i, head.data);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Pop front 20
Index 0: 20
Index 1: 18
Index 2: 16
Index 3: 1000
Index 4: 14
Index 5: 12
Index 6: 10
Index 7: 8
Index 8: 6
Index 9: 4
Index 10: 2
Index 11: 0
Index 12: 100
Size of list: 13
```

It does return the right value (value of the item being popped).

But the re-pointing of head dosen't seem to work.

```
linkedList->head = linkedList->head->next;
```

Comment: Show a minimal verifiable program. For example from the presented code snippet it is unclear what ithe variable head used in the loop means.

Comment: Also it seems the function pop_front is wrong because neither node is deleted.

Comment: Updated with full code example.

Comment: I'd post your `prepend` fnc as `linkedList = prepend(&linkedList)` looks suspicious. In `pop_front`, you should guard against (i.e. check for) `head` being null. `pop_front` probably leaks memory because you don't use `free` [need to see `prepend` to know for sure]. Also, I'd post your struct definition.

Comment: All posted @CraigEstey

Comment: @Jacob Clark  Again I do not see where the variable head used in the loop is declared.

Comment: Add `prepend` too.

Comment: Sorry, prepend added :)

Comment: `head` undeclared at `main`.

Comment: Isn't `size` supposed to decrease by 1 when `pop_front()`ing? And what's the definition of `head`?

Comment: @SHG yes but at the mo pop_front isnt popping anything :(

Comment: `prepend` does _not_ change `linkedList`--it merely operates on it. Because it is a _pointer_ to the struct, changes to `head`, etc. will be updated so caller can see them. So, change to `void prepend(struct LinkedList *linkedList, int data)` [removing the `return` at the bottom] and call with `prepend(&linkedList, i * 2)`

Comment: I'm talking about your implementation of `pop_front()`. Even after it's working it will be another bug.

Comment: An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is the minimal _complete_ program that reproduces your problem. What you've posted doesn't even compile (two people have pointed out that the variable `head` is undeclared and we can't see how it is initialized).

Comment: Updated with the full, compiling program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`head` in your `main()` function is not a pointer to the original list, it's a copy:

```
struct LinkedListNode head = *linkedList.head;
```

After this line, the addresses of `head` and of `*linkedList.head` are **different addresses**.

You'd want to use a pointer instead:

```
struct LinkedListNode *head = linkedList.head;
```

And then updates to this pointer will update the list you wanted to update.

- Also, regardless to this problem, pay attention to all the tips in the comments you've received, and avoid the next bugs.